# Dynamically refresh data on Fragments in ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

I'm developing my first Android app so please bear with me!

The app design will sit an activity and in that activity will have 3 fragments, for brevity lets call them Fragment 1, Fragment 2 and Fragment 3.  In Fragment 1, it will display a bunch of data in TextViews along with a viewpager2 that will take up approximately half the screen for the user to swipe left and right on.  Each of these ViewPager2 fragments will have data that needs to be updated dynamically (refreshed every 5 seconds via gRPC call).  I have searched far and wide on how to do this only to come up short.  I want the refresh to be seamless and the only solution I currently have the whole view flashes when refreshing which is very annoying.  Here's what I have so far:

In Fragment1.java as part of the update function:

```
        fetchUpdateFromServer();

        Service.Loads loadsGroup = data.getLoads();
        int loadCount = loadsGroup.getLoadsCount();
        List<Service.Load> loads = loadsGroup.getLoadsList();

        HashMap<String, Service.Load> newLoadsMap = new HashMap<>();
        HashSet<String> newLoadsSet = new HashSet<>();
        for (Service.Load load : loads) {
            newLoadsMap.put(load.getLoadNumber(), load);
            newLoadsSet.add(load.getLoadNumber());
        }
        List<Fragment> curFragments = adapter.getAllFragments();
            
            // Remove loads that are not in curFrag list
            adapter.removeFragments(newLoadsSet);

            // refresh curFragments after removing old loads
            curFragments = adapter.getAllFragments();

            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getItemCount(); i++) {
                ManifestTableSingleColumn newFrag = new ManifestTableSingleColumn(loads.get(i));
                adapter.refreshFragment(i, newFrag);
            }

            // Add any new fragments
            if (adapter.getItemCount() < loadCount) {
                for (int i = adapter.getItemCount(); i < loadCount; i++) {
                    ManifestTableSingleColumn newFrag = new ManifestTableSingleColumn(loads.get(i));
                    adapter.addFragment(i, newFrag);
                }
            }
```

In TableLayoutAdapter.java

```
private List<Fragment> fragmentList = new LinkedList<>();

    public TableLayoutAdapter(Fragment fragment) {
        super(fragment);
    }

    private int position = -1;


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        this.position = position;
        return this.fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(int index, Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragmentList.add(index, fragment);
        notifyItemChanged(index);
    }

    public void refreshFragment(int index, Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragmentList.set(index, fragment);
        notifyItemChanged(index);
    }

    public void removeFragments(HashSet<String> curLoads) {
        try {
            List<String> loadsToRemove = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < this.fragmentList.size(); i++) {
                ManifestTableSingleColumn curFrag = (ManifestTableSingleColumn) this.fragmentList.get(i);

                if (!curLoads.contains(curFrag.getLoadNumber())) {
                    loadsToRemove.add(curFrag.getLoadNumber());
                }
            }

            for (String load : loadsToRemove) {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.fragmentList.size(); i++) {
                    ManifestTableSingleColumn curFrag = (ManifestTableSingleColumn) this.fragmentList.get(i);
                    if (curFrag.getLoadNumber().equals(load)) {
                        removeFragment(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("myTag", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void removeFragment(int position) {
        try {
            fragmentList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, fragmentList.size());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("myTag", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public List<Fragment> getAllFragments() { return this.fragmentList; }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!